# Highlight active tab in navigation menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

My question is :
I have a menu items, and I want to highlight the active tab that users switch to that points to another page for sure .

stackover flow use :

```
.nav {
    float: left;
    font-size: 125%;
}
.nav ul {
    margin: 0;
}
.nav li {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #777777;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 7px;
}
**.nav .youarehere {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FF9900;
}**
.youarehere a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.nav li:hover {
    background-color: #FF9900;
}
.nav a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Can anybody tell me what else they use to make this work ?

menu :

```
<ul  class="nav">

                      <li> <a  href="{$smarty.const._URL}/index.{$smarty.const._FEXT}" class="wide-nav-link menu_link" >{$lang.homepage}</a></li> 
                      <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle wide-nav-link menu_link " data-toggle="dropdown">{$lang.category} <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu menu_link">
                        {dropdown_menu_video_categories}
                        </ul>
                      </li>

                      {if $smarty.const._MOD_ARTICLE == 1}
                      <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle wide-nav-link menu_link " data-toggle="dropdown">{$lang.articles} <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu menu_link">
                        {dropdown_menu_article_categories}
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      {/if}
                      <li> <a href="{$smarty.const._URL}/topvideos.{$smarty.const._FEXT}" class="wide-nav-link menu_link ">{$lang.top_videos}</a></li>
                      <li><a href="{$smarty.const._URL}/newvideos.{$smarty.const._FEXT}" class="wide-nav-link menu_link">{$lang.new_videos}</a></li>
                      <li><a href="{$smarty.const._URL}/randomizer.php" rel="nofollow" class="wide-nav-link menu_link">{$lang.random_video}</a></li>
                      {if isset($mm_menu_always_inject1)}{$mm_menu_always_inject1}{/if}     
                      <li><a href="{$smarty.const._URL}/contact_us.{$smarty.const._FEXT}" class="wide-nav-link menu_link">{$lang.contact_us}</a></li>

                                            {if isset($mm_menu_always_inject2)}{$mm_menu_always_inject2}{/if}       
                      {if $logged_in != 1 && isset($mm_menu_notlogged_inject)}{$mm_menu_notlogged_inject}{/if}
                    </ul>
```

Comment: Can we have your HTML too please? Also, consider rewording your question, because it is currently difficult to understand

Comment: a) you can use `a:active`, b) you can change the style of the corresponding `a` if it's corresponding content is visible and change it back when the content is hidden with JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can add programmatically class="active" (or selected) to the current selected menu and do this:

`.nav li a.active {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}`

@ChrisHerbert your solution will not work... you will change all the li of the menu... because the class is in your body tag. (**EDIT:** the solution was changed, see comments)

With @ChrisHerbert answer, you can do it in two ways:
1) with Javascript, take the class in the body tag then select the one with the associate index (:eq() in jQuery). (you can find a way without javascript for non-javascript user)
OR
2) you can do: .home .nav li:nth-child(0) {}, .about-us .nav:nth-child(1) {}, etc. if you know the index of each page in your menu! Or other child selector but, old versions of IE don't like it!

I think you should do it with my solution rather then the body tag. Still, it is really useful to have that class in the body for page specific thingy to add.

Comment: Oops!  You're right.  I've edited my answer - forgot to include the classes on the `<li>` elements.

Comment: No problem! I bit redounded though when you could programmatically add  class="active" for example

Comment: If you're adding a body class and a class to the li, there's really no need to do anything with javascript.

Comment: actually, you can do my solution number 2 in Javascript with the index... I'm not quite sure :eq() is valid in old IE versions... but .eq() in jQuery for example works well! you can add .active with the index... but not a really nice way to do it, there's surely better! like I said, body class are really useful, not only for the menu ;)

Comment: I edited my answer, :eq() only exist in jQuery ;) nth-child and all in css

Comment: nth-child has poor IE support as well.

Comment: that's why I wrote: "but, old version of IE don't like it!" ;) just giving all the possibilities, but it's up to the one who ask the question to use what he thinks it's best for its use case!

Comment: Thanks guys! am trying your solutions and will post which has worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Add a unique class to the `<body>` tag of each page.  For example, on the home page:

```
<body class="home">
```

On the contact page: `<body class="contact">`

On the blog page: `<body class="blog">`

..and so on.

Then, in your CSS, do something like this:

```
.home .nav li.home, .contact .nav li.contact, .blog .nav li.blog {
  // styling to indicate active state
}
```

Comment: added body tag with the unique class for each tpl file (home.tpl; contact.tpl) and defined css as you said ;what may be wrong with this ?please focus with me a bit more.

Comment: updated my question here is tpl code for menu in file header.tpl (dynamic)

Comment: Add a class the matching `li` as well.

Comment: do i need maybe some php function ?

Comment: No, this is just HTML and CSS

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is, are you looking to have this done dynamically? Or are you coding each page? The other two solutions are great, but a bit overkill if actually you're accessing each page individually. You could just add a class to the selected nav element depending on the page. This is probably the easiest to get your head around if you've not done it before, but @ChrisHerbert's solution is the nicest way of doing it dynamically just using CSS (no PHP ifs etc).

**HTML**

```
<div class="nav">
<a href="home">Home</a>
<a href="about-us">About us</a>
<a href="portfolio" class="selected">Portfolio</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.nav a {
color:#ff4444;
}
.nav a.selected {
color:#ff44ff;
}
```

EDIT: Just realised that @AnnieCaron's answer is the same as mine.